# Extend SimpleJpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot, when I want to extend `SimpleJpaRepository` like this interface:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{}
```

and this implementation:

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID>
{
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        super(domainClass, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'Class<T>' type found.
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories

Comment: You should not write a *class* implementing `JpaRepository`.
Instead you should write an *interface* extending `JpaRepository`, and Spring will generate an implementing class automatically.
You can find examples in [Getting started with Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch, i want to write something like section 1.3.2 of https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: @JBNizet, i got "Could not autowire. No beans of 'JpaEntityInformation<T, ?>' type found." error when using this method!

Comment: Did you annotate it with NoRepositoryBean as shown in the documentation?

Comment: @JBNizet, yes :(

Answer (score 12):

When trying to make an implementation of `JpaRepository` through extending `SimpleJpaRepository`, it is important that spring knows you are doing this. By default spring will try to create a `SimpleJpaRepository`, even if you extend it. Therefore your new implementation of the `SimpleJpaRepository` will not be populated, created or even remotely available. Therefore all repositories extending your new custom repository will **not be created either**.

To solve this problem, one should add some repository config. More specifically you need to provide a `repositoryBaseClass` in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation; e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryImpl.class
)
```

Usually you already have some config class to provide your `DataSource`-bean, `EntityManager`-bean and/or `JpaTransactionManager`-bean. As a general best-practice I suggest placing it over there.

Sometimes spring gets a little confused when you do this and still doesn't manage to find your newly defined `repositoryBaseClass`. In that case, help the spring repository autowirer a little and also provide a basepackage, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryImpl.class,
    basePackages = {
        "be.your.company.your.path.to.your.repositories"
    }
)
```

Comment: YOU... ARE... THE... MAN!!!
After a million hours trying to figure out this godforsaken problem, I finally hit your answer... I can't upvote this answer enough, but I can do the next best thing.

Comment: Haha, I remember when I made this answer that I went through quite the journey to find a solution myself. Glad I could be of any help! Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much.  Been working for 5 days to get past this on our migration from Spring4 to Spring6.  It was the right combination of clues to restructuring my packages and config xml.   In Spring6, if you have to be more careful about use a base-class and package the classes to get the right combination of hiding the custom repository and yet specifying it only for the repositories you need it.  I had a subpackage that needed to be moved out from underneath another package of repositories.

Answer (score 2):

**Make a interface extending JpaRepository**

For eg -

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity,Integer>,RepositoryCustom // this is our custom repository{


}
```

**Repository Custom is a Interface**

```
public interface RepositoryCustom {


    List<Entity> getAll(); // define the method signature here


}
```

**Implementing the Custom Interface**

```
@Transactional
public class RepositoryImpl implements  RepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext // this will inject em in your class
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    write the method body and return

}
```

> Keep in mind the Repository naming convention . If the Interface name
>   is Repository . then the custom interface shuld be named as
>   Repository and the implementation as Repository

Comment: thank you, but this is "Adding custom behavior to single repositories" (section 1.3.1 of https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), i want to implement "Adding custom behavior to all repositories" (section 1.3.2 of above URL)

Comment: For a more elaborate answer (including `why do we need to create three classes`) wrt. all kinds repository customizations, you can also read my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73895512/1493235).