# SimpleJpaRepository argument compilation error

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I try to extends SimpleJpaRepository and I have got an error :

```
[ERROR]     constructor org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.SimpleJpaRepository(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation<com.bnpparibas.dsibddf.ap00437.successione2e.domain.entity.gedeo.Contrat,?>,javax.persistence.EntityManager) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR]     constructor org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.SimpleJpaRepository(java.lang.Class<com.bnpparibas.dsibddf.ap00437.successione2e.domain.entity.gedeo.Contrat>,javax.persistence.EntityManager) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I tried the @enableJpaRepositories solution like described here :
[Extend SimpleJpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403857/extend-simplejparepository)
But it does not work.
I put the annotation in the repository class.

Is there something else I can do?

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = ContratRepository.class , basePackages = {"com.bnpparibas.dsibddf.ap00437.successione2e.infrastructure.repository"})
@Repository
public class ContratRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<Contrat,Integer> implements IContratRepository {

    @Override
    public Contrat save(Contrat contrat) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

if I had as suggested by eclipse the constructor 2:

```
    public ContratRepository(Class<Contrat> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }
```

Contrat class

```
package com.bnpparibas.dsibddf.ap00437.successione2e.domain.entity.gedeo;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Contrat {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType. IDENTITY )
  private String idContratTech;

  private String contractExternalId;

  private String code;

  private String libelle;

  private String contractStatus;

  public String getIdContratTech() {
    return idContratTech;
}

public void setIdContratTech(String idContratTech) {
    this.idContratTech = idContratTech;
}

public String getContractExternalId() {
    return contractExternalId;
}

public void setContractExternalId(String contractExternalId) {
    this.contractExternalId = contractExternalId;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getLibelle() {
    return libelle;
}

public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
    this.libelle = libelle;
}

public String getContractStatus() {
    return contractStatus;
}

public void setContractStatus(String contractStatus) {
    this.contractStatus = contractStatus;
}

public String getNature() {
    return nature;
}

public void setNature(String nature) {
    this.nature = nature;
}

private String nature;


  public void foo() {
  }

}
```

I have got the error:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Class<com.bnpparibas.dsibddf.ap00437.successione2e.domain.entity.gedeo.Contrat>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

that I don't understand

thanks for your help

Comment: Please share your Contrat code as well @Kim

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should not put `@Repository` and `@Configuration` on the same class.
Secondly, if you are to extend a `SimpleJpaRepository`, you need to create matching constructors and call the parent constructors.
Thirdly, I would like to note that customizing a `SimpleJpaRepository` is **NOT ADVISED FOR A SINGLE ENTITY** (e.g. `Contrat`). In that case, use a regular repository implementation! If you do customize your SimpleJpaRepository to be only compatible with a single entity, you will **not be able** to create **other repositories extending SimpleJpaRepository**!

## 1. About beans and configuration

In Spring, a `Repository` is a type of **bean**. This means that it this class can be automatically instantiated by the Spring framework when you need an instance of it (ever noticed that you never need to do `new MyRepository()`?). This is done through a process called *autowiring* (the general principle of this is called [*Dependency Injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You can read more about beans and autowiring in spring [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html). Other typical types of beans are `@Component`, `@Controller` and `@Service`.

A `Configuration` class on the other hand is a whole different kind of beast. [Configuration classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html) are used to provide **logic** about how certain beans are to be created.

> An example could for instance be that you want to configure a bean that holds a database connection, and in order to create that bean you need variables that are read from the environment (Environment Variables). In that example the configuration class would be the one reading out the environment variables and creating the database connection bean through a `@Bean` method.

In essence configuration classes are thus used to instantiate beans that either 1) are not able to be instantiated automatically or 2) need special bean configuration.

## 2. About matching constructors

Spring needs to be able to instantiate the parent class `SimpleJpaRepository`. Therefore, you should assure that you implement matching constructors.
Furthermore, it is a general best practice to split your repository in a `Repository` and a `RepositoryImpl`.

So for the constructor matching, this gives:

**CustomSimpleRepositoryImpl**

```java
public class CustomSimpleRepositoryImpl(<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> extends CustomSimpleRepository<T, ID> {

    private EntityManager em;
    private JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> ei;

    protected CustomSimpleRepositoryImpl(@NonNull Class<T> entityClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.em = em;
        this.ei= JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(entityClass, em);
    }

    public CustomSimpleRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.em = entityManager;
        this.ei = entityInformation;
    }

    /* Whatever you want to put in your repository */
}
```

For the split:
**CustomSimpleRepository**

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>  {
    /* Whatever you want to put in your repository */
}
```

## 3. Customizing repositories

Note that in the above example I did not use `@Repository` whatsoever. Instead I used `@NoRepositoryBean`. This is because in my example I implemented a *generic `SimpleJpaRepository` replacement*. This repository is not to be instantiated on its own!

### 3.1 A plain, custom repository

If you rather want to customize a regular `Repository`, please only use an interface `CustomRepository` and an implementation called `CustomRepositoryImpl`.

Example implementations can be found in 3.2.

### 3.2 A custom repository extending SimpleJpaRepository

This is a difficult one: you cannot implement an interface without providing all of its unimplemented methods. So if you really want a repository where you can have both:

1. JPA methods, e.g. `findById`, `findByFieldContainsText(String text)`...
2. Custom methods, e.g. `findAllCountsGroupByParentId()`, `...`

It is not possible by creating one single repository interface or class. Instead, you need to create a custom repository where you offload your "custom methods" (2) and a repository that extends `SimpleJpaRepository` where you define your "JPA methods" (1):

[image]

**CustomJpaRepository.java**

```java
@Repository
public interface CustomJpaRepository
        extends JpaRepository<CustomEntity, Long>
        extends CustomRepository {
    /* Your desired JPA methods, e.g. */
    // findByNameContainsText(String text);
}
```

**CustomRepository.java**

```java
public interface CustomRepository {
    /* Your desired custom methods, e.g. */
    // findAllCountsWhereContractFinishedGroupByBusinessUnitId();
}
```

**CustomRepositoryImpl.java**

```java
@Repository
public class CustomRepositoryImpl {

    protected EntityManager em;

    CustomRepositoryImpl(final EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
 
    /* Your desired custom methods, e.g. */
    // public findAllCountsWhereContractFinishedGroupByBusinessUnitId() {
    //    ...
    // }
}
```

Since your `CustomJpaRepository` extends `JpaRepository`, you can use the JPA methods.
Since it also extends `CustomRepository`, it inherits the custom methods.
Result: you can call both kinds of methods (custom and jpa) combined in `CustomJpaRepository`.